# Dexie JS - Combining Condition Filters and Text Search

Tags: javascript, full-text-search, dexie

I have read a variety of posts and examples on combining `and` and `or` statements in a Dexie query, and I'm still confused.

My `tasks` query begins by filtering out certain attributes based on the app's UI state. For example, I want to view tasks by project, and by whether or not they are completed or deleted. These conditions are all indexed when my database is initialized.

```
var where = null

switch(selectedProject){
  case 'inbox': 
    where = { project: '', completed: filterCompleted, deleted: 0 }
    break
  case 'my-tasks':
    where = { assignee: sessionStorage.userId, completed: filterCompleted, deleted: 0 }
    break
  default:
    where = { project: selectedProject, completed: filterCompleted, deleted: 0 }
}

//Ready to go...
tasks = await db.tasks.where(where).sortBy('order')
```

In addition to these ways of viewing different task states, I also have a text search field for filtering down the remaining tasks in a list. I can get it to work great with the following ***if I omit the above*** `where` conditions:

```
//searchText is the user's input text in the search field
let searchTerms = searchText.split(' ')

tasks = await db.tasks
  .where('name').anyOfIgnoreCase(searchTerms)
  .or('name').startsWithIgnoreCase(searchText)
  .or('notesPlain').anyOfIgnoreCase(searchTerms)
  .sortBy('order')
```

Where I'm struggling is how to combine the initial UI state's `where` clause and the above text search. I've tried append this to the above code, but it doesn't work:

```
...
.sortBy('order')
.filter(function(task){ 
  return task.project == selectedProject && task.completed == filterCompleted && task.deleted == 0
})
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can do it like this:

```
 tasks = (await db.tasks
  .where('name').anyOfIgnoreCase(searchTerms)
  .or('name').startsWithIgnoreCase(searchText)
  .or('notesPlain').anyOfIgnoreCase(searchTerms)
  .sortBy('order'))
.filter(function(task){ 
  return task.project == selectedProject && task.completed == filterCompleted && task.deleted == 0
})
```

The sortBy returns a Promise so you need to wrap with the await to get the Collection object.